# Set dynamic value for parent in state in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying open uibmodal in angular but the parent state must change as per request of previous state.

My code of state.js -

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('save', {
                    parent: 'app',
                    url: '/save',
                    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'app/save.html',
                            controller: 'SaveController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            size: 'lg'

                        });
                    }]
                });
    }
})();
```

Controller code looks like this -

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('SaveController', SaveController);

    SaveController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance','$state', '$scope','$stateParams' ];

    function SaveController($uibModalInstance, $state, $scope, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;
        var id = $state.params.id;
       }
    })();
```

I am trying to redirect to that state from parent state controller using:

```
 $state.go("save",{id: 2, name:'test'});
```

I want to change parent state value as per request via controller, please suggest any possible solution for that.

Comment: Show please parent state code. Also you could try  $state.go("save",{id: 2, name:'test'}, {reload: true});

Comment: it won't work because I want to change parent state from requested page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing the root part:

```
$state.go("app.save",{id: 2, name:'test'});
```

this is the doc: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: but I want to change on each request of state and it gives an error as "Could not resolve 'app.save' from state 'app'